Why does nesting Pager2's list get stuck in Resume?
I want show data by Type.Data has 5 Types.
list activity and fragment:

MainActivity : entrance.
DeviceRepairManageActivity : has a FragmentContainerView.
DeviceRepairPageFragment : toolbar,tablayout,ViewPager2(use FragmentStateAdapter)
DeviceRepairListFragment : RecyclerView(use TextView display String)
ShowFragment :Empty Fragment

process：

In MainActivity click button to DeviceRepairManageActivity.
FragmentContainerView default startDestination is deviceRepairPageFragment.
pull down generate data show by RecyclerView in ViewPager2(more than 1 page).
click tablayout croll to other page and pull down (more than 1 page).
click item navigation to ShowFragment.
clcik backbutton in showFragment ，back to deviceRepairPageFragment.


now ,navigation anim(x 0 to 100%) is stack a little time.
7. click tablayout scroll to 0 page.
now ,no show scroll anim and stack a little time.
8. show 0 page data.

How to fix stuttering, or what I did wrong, thank you in advance for your answer
this is my Minimal implementation code click to my github project
